# Firebase Realtime Database not working with my Discord bot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, discord.js

I wanted to use the firebase realtime database using my Discord Bot. But I am facing the issue as mentioned in the title. There are similar issues but NOT related to this.

My Code:

```
//import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
import Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client(); 

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  const userMessage = message.content
  console.log(`Message: ${userMessage}`)


  if (userMessage.startsWith('/body')) {
    //console.log(message.content);
    return message.channel.send(JSON.stringify(message))
  } else if (userMessage === '/add') {
    return admin.database().ref(`/parent/child/`).set({ "child1": 123, "child2": 456 }).then(() => {
      return message.channel.send('Added in database :/')
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  } else {
    console.log(message.content)
    return 0
  }
});

client.login(config.token); // <-- Gives the error from here
```

Go I get the error in the last line. So I decided to run the code on local terminal. The code ran but when I used the command and, this occurs:

```
FirebaseError: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.
  at FirebaseDatabaseError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\Dharmarai\Documents\discordBotTest\functions\node modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:42:28)
  at new FirebaseDatabaseError (C:\Users\Dharmarai\Documents\discordBotTest\functions\node modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:203:23)
  at DatabaseService.ensureUrl (C:\Users\Dharmarai\Documents\discordBotTest\functions\node modules\firebase-admin\lib\database\database.js:88:15)
  at DatabaseService.getDatabase (C:\Users\Dharmarai\Documents\discordBotTest\functions\node modules\firebase-admin\lib\database\database.js:55:26)
  at FirebaseApp.database (C:\Users\Dharmarai\Documents\discordBotTest\functions\node modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-app.js:231:24)
  at FirebaseNamespace.fn (C:\Users\Dharmarai\Documents\discordBotTest\functions\node modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js:279:45)
  at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dharmaraj\Documents\discordBotTest\functions\src\index.js:46:22)
  at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
  at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Dharmarai\Documents\discordBotTest\functions\node modulesXdiscord.is\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
  at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Dharmarai\Documents\discordBotTest\functions\node modulesXdiscord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE CREATE.js:4:32) { 
errorlnfo: {
  code : 'database/invalid-argument ,
  message: "Can't determine Firebase Database URL."
}
```

I just want to add data in Database when command is ran in Discord

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show images with text.  Copy the text into the question itself so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not work on a sense of urgency.  Volunteers will answer the question when they have time, you provide sufficient information, and if you make it easy for them to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
admin.initializeApp({
        
        databaseURL: "<url>"
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.